# How can DOMRect width or height be negative?

Tags: javascript, getboundingclientrect

The [`DOMRect` documentation](https://drafts.fxtf.org/geometry-1/#DOMRect) says width and height can be negative

> **width dimension** The width of the rectangle. Can be negative.
>
> **height dimension** The height of the rectangle. Can be negative.

Can someone explain how negative width or height values could occur?

Comment: _When the rectangle has a non-negative width dimension, the rectangle’s horizontal origin is the left edge; otherwise, it is **the right edge**. Similarly, when the rectangle has a non-negative height dimension, the rectangle’s vertical origin is the top edge; otherwise, it is **the bottom edge**._ Imho that explains how they occur.

Comment: @hindmost Right but how can one produce an element for which the width or height is negative?

Comment: If I understood correct, that's just an abstract interface and it isn't necessarily related to DOM element in general case.